# clang++ 9.0.1 with -stdlib=libc++ cannot find <optional>

Tags: c++, clang, c++17, clang++, libc++

I'm on Manjaro Linux with clang++ 9.0.1.

I'm testing std::optional in C++17. When I compile without `-stdlib=libc++`, the test cpp file compiles without error. However, if I specify `-stdlib=libc++`, clang++ shows the following error:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++17 --stdlib=libc++ test.cpp
test.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'optional' file not found
#include <optional>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Could you please tell me what I should do if I need to compile it with `-stdlib=libc++`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of `libc++` do you have?

Comment: Did you follow: https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html#using-libc-on-linux

Comment: Also note that on some Linux distros, the libc++ packages are really out of date, so you will need the following to install libc++: https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/BuildingLibcxx.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @nathanoliver and @rian-quinn. I find myself so stupid -- I haven't installed libc++. The error got solved by `sudo pacman -S libc++`.